# How can I verify a token that I generate in my flutter application on my nodejs server using the firebase sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, jwt

I simply want to verify a token that I generate in my Flutter application with google firebase.
I login correctly I get the user token but when I send it to my nodejs server I can't verify it.

First I tried to verify it with Jsonwebtoken without success then I configured the sdk as it says in the documentation:

[Google Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIpqu.png)
I generate the private key, import it from the json and initialize the sdk.

I have seen another configuration but this one does not work because if I put it says that it does not find the property pricate_key this is the google configuration:
[image config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7qx3.png)
Config located in General of the console:
[Image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRNj2.png)

I have tried a lot of things but for the last one I leave you this code wanting to validate using the google sdk:

```
export const validarJWTGoogle = async (req, res = response, next) => { Leer token const token = req.header('x-token'); if (!token) { return res.status(401).json({ ok: false, msg: 'No hay token en la petición' });
    }

const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
    //obtengo el kid para saber que certificado usar const kid = decodedToken.header.kid;
    //Obtengo los certificados de google const response = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com'); let allCert =  response.data; const cert = allCert[kid]; admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
        .then((decodedToken) => { const uid = decodedToken.uid; El token es válido y hemos extraído el UID del usuario console.log(uid);
        })
        .catch((error) => { El token no es válido console.error(error);
        });

};
```

The error I always get is:

[image: code error]

I also tried to verify the token with this code from jsonwebtoken:

```
jwt.verify(token, cert, (err, decoded) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error al verificar el token:', err);
  else {
    console.log('Token verificado correctamente:', decoded);
  }
});
```

Getting the same error

I have checked on the website: https://jwt.io/ that the token is correct and it is.
I have also verified the certificates that google returns and that my token value in the kid parameter is obtained.

I don't know what else to try thank you very much in advance I would appreciate any documentation whatsoever.

I have tried with the google sdk and with jsonwebtoken
I have verified that the token is correct and that the .json file that google gives me to initialize is correct.
I deleted the project, reconfigured it and generated the json again.
I have tried to put the configuration in an environment variable in my system.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages,  code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 0):

In the end my mistake was that by using log from the 'package:logger/logger.dart' package; I was truncating the console output of the token.

Be careful it also happens with print()

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 es el tamaño de cada fragmento
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) {
    print(match.group(0));
  });
```

}

final code:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
 try {
const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
req.uid = decodedToken.uid;
next();
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(401).json({ ok: false, msg: 'Token no válido' });
  }
```